# Linear Regression prediction by Date in python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I have converted date into numerical values but I am stuck on next step how to preparing data for prediction, How to use date for prediction in python code? How to count eventhappen attribute Please guide me and improve my code where it does not make any sense. Below is my code

```
#Here is Dataset

    date          Eventhappen
    2016-01-14    A
    2016-01-15    C
    2016-01-16    B
    2016-01-17    A
    2016-01-18    C
    2016-02-18    B

#Converting Date into Numerical Value

    df['Dispatch_Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dispatch_Date_Time'])
    df.set_index('Dispatch_Date_Time', inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    df['month'] = df.index.month
    df['year'] = df.index.year
    df['day'] = df.index.day
    df['eventhappen'] = 1

#Preparing the data

    X = df[['year']]
    y = df['eventhappen']

#Trainng the Algorithm
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Making the Predictions
    y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

#Plotting the Least Square Line
    sns.pairplot(df, x_vars=['year'], y_vars='eventhappen', size=7, aspect=0.7, kind='reg')
```

Comment: What are you trying to model here? From this, it looks like you're going to regress a column of 1s against the year of the date column, though not even that since `X_train` and `y_train` are not defined anywhere.

Comment: I suggest converting the dates into "days since 2016-01-14" as this would give numeric data to model.

Comment: ALollz Sorry for that That training code is missing here leave it here please focus on my question

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of confusion in your code, for me at least. The column names are not the same used in the processing.You have two scenarios to consider :

SN-A : If you want to predict which event is happening on some future date, the target column which is 'Eventhappen' will be categorical, you have a multi-classification task not a regression one, so you should encode your target column, then split your dataset using train/test split and finally implement a classifier to predict the event on some future date.

SN-B : If you want to predict the number of the events happening on some future date, then you are on the right way, you should have a numerical column to predict which is the count. It means that this line of code should not be a constant :

```
df['eventhappen'] = 1
```

When you have it, you should consider some timeseries techniques (power transformation, lags...), then split into train/test datasets and finally implement/evaluate your regressor model.

Use this function to extract the features needed from the date column and then use them directly in your machine learning model. You can also encode the cyclic features, that gives the model the ability to extract cyclic insights from the data.

```
def transform_col_date(data, date_col):
  '''
  data : Dataframe (Your dataset).
  date_col : String (name of the date column)
  '''
  data_ = data.copy()
  data_.reset_index(inplace=True)
  data_[date_col] = pd.to_datetime(data_[date_col], infer_datetime_format = True)
  data_['day'] = data_[date_col].dt.day
  data_['month'] = data_[date_col].dt.month
  data_['dayofweek'] = data_[date_col].dt.dayofweek
  data_['dayofyear'] = data_[date_col].dt.dayofyear
  data_['quarter'] = data_[date_col].dt.quarter
  data_['weekofyear'] = data_[date_col].dt.weekofyear
  data_['year'] = data_[date_col].dt.year

  return data_

#in your case
data = transform_col_date(df, 'date')
```